# Spring Autowiring all beans from Qualifier in Map

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

Is it possible to have a custom `qualifier` in spring and return in a `Map<MyEnum, Bean>`?
Example code:

```
enum class MyEnum {
  TYPE1,
  TYPE2
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class MyQualifier(val value: MyEnum)


interface BaseBean

@Service
@MyQualifier(MyEnum.TYPE1)
class Bean1: BaseBean

@Service
@MyQualifier(MyEnum.TYPE2)
class Bean2: BaseBean

@Service
class MyService @Autowired constructor(private val types: Map< MyEnum, BaseBean>)
```

So how could I inject all the beans with my custom qualifier into this `Map`? in the `service`? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried implementing a `BeanFactory`?

Comment: @AndreArtus I know it's possible to create the map in a `BeanFactory` or even with a `Bean` in a `Configuration` class, but I was just wondering if this approach I asked is possible...

Comment: I don't know if it's possible out of the [metaphorical] box. I know you can pass a map via XML config, but you want to pick it up through reflection (if I understand the question).

Comment: @AndreArtus exactly... I currently have a `@Configuration` class creating a `@Bean` for this map, which works but it is not what I wanted...